# Proof that it is impossible to make a hyper-cube that covers all but one of the vertices of another hyper-cube.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Let's say you have a hyper-cube of $d$-dimensions $A$. How can you prove that there is no $d$-hyper-cube $B$, that encloses all the vertices of $A$ except for one.

I was thinking of a proof by contradiction but it seems incomplete/not rigurous.

WLOG, we can set our hyper-cube $A$ to be the hyper-cube made by permuting the $2^d$ coordinates $( \pm 1, \pm1,...)$.

Since we do not want to enclose ONLY one vertex, choose a random vertex $V_{out}$ which we don't want covered by $B$ and is located in some arbitrary $d-1$-face $F$.

Since we don't want just one vertex, we want all the other vertices inside $B$. Therefore, all of the vertices on the opposite $d-1$-face $F_{op}$ (or is it called $d-1$-cell?), should be inside $B$.

Then, for $B$ to cover those vertices on $F$, since it is the opposite $d-1$-face, it has to grow the distance from $F$ to $F_{op}$. Since all vertices on $F$ are separated by the same distance to those in $F_{op}$, $B$ has to grow enough to cover all of them.

Therefore, we must cover all of the points in $F$, so singling one out is impossible.

I'm trying to do the same for excluding $2^{d-1} - d$ vertices.

Comment: Are you making additional assumptions like the hypercubes cannot be rotated against each other? If not, it seems to me that your statement is incorrect.

Comment: No. But thanks for the insight!

Comment: As marmot said, the statement as it currently is, is incorrect. In 2D, make a square with side length the diagonal of A, and with one side exactly on top of a diagonal. The new square contains 3 of the 4 vertices of A. The construct easily generalises to higher dimension, since there always exists a half space that contains all but one vertex of a hypercube. In fact for any finite set of $n$ (distinct) points, you can always find a hyperplane with $k$ points above, and $n-k$ points below.